# was the sentence below correct the queen has given us everything

Tags: sentence-construction

Was the sentence below correct?

> The Queen has given us everything!

That sentence was constructed by the Present Perfect Tense. Nevertheless, I have known that the Present Perfect Tense sentence should include the time reference like since or for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is correct.  There is no need for a "since" phrase.

There are two main uses for present perfect:

1. For states that continue until the present time.
2. For actions in the past with effect in the present.

For the first use you usually have a "since" or "for" phrase. It is incorrect to use a since or for phrase in the second sense.

> I have lived in Japan since 2016.     *Implying that you still live in Japan*.

> I have climbed Mt Fuji.   (An action in the past that gives me an experience that I think about in the present)

It would be wrong to say "I have climbed Mt Fuji since 2016"

Likewise "The Queen has given us everything." refers to action in the past with an effect in the present.  It would be incorrect to use "since".

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is grammatically correct.

> The Queen has given us everything.

When you ask if a sentence is correct, or not, that can be construed to mean, "is the following true or false". Under that interpretation, it is **not** correct that the queen gave them everything. Undoubtably, the people in question breathed air while they were alive. I doubt that the queen manufactured the air herself.